# Как сделать переключения RTS использую библиотеку libmodbus?

Tags: c++, linux, c

Использую RS485 нужно научить master общаться со slave (за slave взято устройство со встроенным modbus) master пишется на BeagleBone. Использую библиотеку libmodbus научил master общаться по RS232 но в дальнейшем нужно использовать RS485 нашел в библиотеки есть встроенные функции которые позволяют переключать во время rts.Но переключения  rts не происходит для переключения использую gpio7. Вопрос прост в чем проблема и как исправить ?

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "modbus-rtu.h"
#define GPIO_PATH   "/sys/class/gpio"
#define GPIO21_PATH "/sys/class/gpio/gpio7"
#include <linux/tty.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

void *set_rts(modbus_t *ctx,int a)
{
    FILE *io, *iodir, *ioval;
    io = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/unexport", "w");


    if (io == NULL)
    {
        printf("1can not open file\n");
        //return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf(io, "7");
    fclose(io);
    io = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/export", "w");
    //fseek(io, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fprintf(io, "%d", 7);

    fclose(io);
    iodir = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio7/direction", "w");
    //fseek(iodir, 0, SEEK_SET);



    ioval = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio7/value", "w");
    //fseek(ioval, 0, SEEK_SET);

    if(a == 1)
    {
        fprintf(iodir, "out");
        fprintf(ioval, "%d", 1);

    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(iodir, "in");
        fprintf(ioval, "%d", 0);

    }

    fclose(iodir);

    fclose(ioval);
}
int main(void)
{

        int connected;
    modbus_t *ctx;
    uint16_t tab_reg[64];
    uint32_t t = 5;
    float avgVLL = -1; 
    int rc;
    int i;

    struct timeval response_timeout;
    uint32_t tv_sec = 0;
    uint32_t tv_usec = 0;
    response_timeout.tv_sec = 3;
    response_timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    ctx = modbus_new_rtu("/dev/ttyS4", 9600, 'N', 8, 1);

//

        if (ctx == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create the libmodbus context\n");
        return -1;

    }
    modbus_get_response_timeout(ctx, &tv_sec, &tv_usec); 
    printf("Default response timeout:%d sec %d usec \n", tv_sec, tv_usec);

    tv_sec = 15;
    tv_usec = 8;

    modbus_set_response_timeout(ctx, tv_sec, tv_usec); 
    modbus_get_response_timeout(ctx, &tv_sec, &tv_usec); 
    printf("Set response timeout:%d sec %d usec \n", tv_sec, tv_usec);
    modbus_set_slave(ctx, 1);
    modbus_set_debug(ctx, TRUE);
    connected = modbus_connect(ctx);

    printf("modbus_set_slave return: %d\n", rc);
    if (rc != 0)
    {
        printf("modbus_set_slave: %s \n", modbus_strerror(errno));
    }
    rc = modbus_rtu_set_serial_mode(ctx, MODBUS_RTU_RS485);
modbus_rtu_set_rts(ctx, MODBUS_RTU_RTS_UP);
 modbus_rtu_set_custom_rts(ctx, set_rts(ctx,1));
    printf("modbus_rtu_set_serial_mode: %d \n", rc);

    if (rc != 0)
    {
        printf("modbus_rtu_set_serial_mode: %s \n", modbus_strerror(errno));
    }
    //modbus_set_byte_timeout(ctx, t, t);  modbus_read_bits(ctx, 0, 3, tab_reg);
    while(true)
    {

        rc =  modbus_read_registers(ctx, 0, 3, tab_reg);

        if (rc == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", modbus_strerror(errno));

            //return -1;
        }
        else
        {



            for (i = 0; i < rc; i++) {
                printf("reg[%d]=%d (0x%X)\n", i, tab_reg[i], tab_reg[i]);

            }
            break;
        }
    }
    modbus_close(ctx);
    modbus_free(ctx);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RS485 и RS232 и UART отличаются аппаратно. Нужна вам микросхемка преобразователя уровня сирналов. скорее всего в Beagleboarg у вас получился UART.

К нему припаивается микросхема. [Тут вот обсуждают как оно работает](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/244425/how-is-this-rs485-module-working). Готовых схем-сборок полно в онлайн-магазинах.

Comment: Необязательно, rs485 режим часто есть в современных rs232 портах, нужно только электрическое согласование (пару проводов из чипа развязать с линией).

Comment: Да, а в драйвере 8250 в Linux уже несколько релизов есть эмуляция rs485, которая сама дёргает rts в правильные моменты. Я уже говорил это топик стартеру в каком-то из предыдущих вопросов.

Comment: так у него в коде порт эмулированный на gpio. он также может по 485ому дергаться? да и конвертор стоит 100рублей...

Comment: железка у меня стоит rs485, а про драйвер 8250 не могли бы пояснить то есть когда подключаю в этой строчке   ctx = modbus_new_rtu("/dev/ttyS4", 9600, 'N', 8, 1); мне нужно за место ttyS4 указать serial 8250 или использовать библиотеку просьба объяснить